# Creating a list from another list's value

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting, data-validation

How can I populate a cell with a list as a result of a condition from another dropdown list? 
I have a dropdown list, when I select a value from it I will need to populate the cell beside it with items related to that value and list it as a dropdown as well.

Comment: I believe you will find this helpful: http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html